# if dependencies were already baked in in dist.js by webpack, why does npm still download the dependencies in the package.json when installing

Tags: npm, webpack, node-modules, package.json, umd

I'm building a umd library using webpack, in my `package.json` I have `dependency-a` which I use in my code.

When I build my code using webpack, I see that `dependency-a` is already baked in in the `dist/bundle.js`, then I publish my code to npm.

When the user installs my package from npm, all the code the user needs is already in `dist/bundle.js`, but why does npm still transitively install the `dependency-a` in my package's `node_modules`? When will the `node_modules/dependency-a` in my package's directory ever be used?

Did I misunderstand something? 
Am I supposed to A). exclude this dependency from npm or B). make webpack not bake the dependency in in `dist/bundle.js`?

What are the best / most common practices?